# Typescript class getter and setter not called

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class `BarWrapper`:

```js
export default class BarWrapper extends SVGGElement {
    get barGroup(): null | BarGroup {
        if (!this.hasChildNodes()) {
            return null;
        }
        console.log('get barGroup');
        return this.querySelector(".bar-group");
    }

    set barGroup(element: BarGroup) {
        this.querySelector(".bar-group").remove();
        console.log('set barGroup');
        this.appendChild(element);
    }

    get handleGroup(): null | HandleGroup {
        if (!this.hasChildNodes()) {
            return null;
        }
        console.log('get handleGroup');
        return this.querySelector(".handle-group");
    }

    set handleGroup(element: HandleGroup) {
        this.querySelector(".handle-group").remove();
        console.log('set handleGroup');
        this.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

class `BarGroup`:

```js
export default class BarGroup extends SVGGElement{
    get bar() : null | SVGRectElement{
        if(!this.hasChildNodes()){
            return null;
        }

        return this.querySelector(".bar");
    }

    set bar(element : SVGGElement){
        console.log('set bar');
        this.querySelector(".bar").remove();
        this.appendChild(element);
    }

    get progressBar() : null | SVGRectElement{
        if(!this.hasChildNodes()){
            return null;
        }

        return this.querySelector(".bar-progress");
    }

    set progressBar(element : SVGGElement){
        console.log('set progressBar');
        this.querySelector(".bar-progress").remove();
        this.appendChild(element);
    }

    get text() : null | SVGTextElement{
        if(!this.hasChildNodes()){
            return null;
        }

        return this.querySelector(".bar-label");
    }

    set text(element : SVGTextElement){
        console.log('set text');
        this.querySelector(".bar-label").remove();
        this.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

and some `index.ts`:

```js
function createSVG(tag: string, attrs): SVGElement {
    const svgElement: SVGElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (let attr in attrs) {
        if (attr === 'append_to') {
            const parent = attrs.append_to;
            parent.appendChild(svgElement);
        } else if (attr === 'innerHTML') {
            svgElement.innerHTML = attrs.innerHTML;
        } else {
            svgElement.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
    }
    return svgElement;
}

let bar_wrapper = <BarWrapper>createSVG('g', {
            class: ('bar-wrapper ' + (this.task.custom_class || '')).trim(),
            'data-id': this.task.id,
        });
        bar_wrapper.barGroup = <BarGroup>createSVG('g', {
            class: 'bar-group',
        });
        bar_wrapper.handleGroup = <HandleGroup>createSVG('g', {
            class: 'handle-group',
        });
```

Now essentially what I would expect to happen is that when running this code that I would get `set barGroup` as output but that doesn't happen. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

The code should also be executable on [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=56&ssc=18&pln=56&pc=20#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwM4GtkG8BQyRyA+hCACYBcyAInJANyHEmgUQAeNIArgLYAjaM2KkMYOFDA16TFkQS8JAe34kEAG0wYaEqKADmo4hwAO5DiATAIu5PqPIAPg7AGQhgNoBdE0UsaOBAAT39kYGpkYLCFCJAANzhNSJpBFRVNCGDwkDh+CD13I3CzKBVDKDt7PiEROIkpGWjQ5gBffHwtHWQACWCKLIBxct4zZC5ISgxkAGUANSGhgFEsgvACMUMIMGQDQwALMH7KLIAKAEpkHl5NTRc5xYAlCAQwVYh1sE2xYmAYM4AQjAB2AGAAdAdMABhUGaCgAORUHAwlwuP1+vyqYF4UBAyD4d3CYg6cTE2Nx+JBYPBAEdeNAQrMIFk3iooGcAESQgZZcH7I6ci7hUliDA7PbAQ7HXkQM4sz7kXY0BZLD5fdFk4jUiH0xnM1lgdlcnmnCD8qWCi6A-mfFQJOXCrVEHXguBmCyUWHAeHytZKp0kzpbCVZGAys2Xa4E273Vyql5vdVKjG-f5A11QjDe+FIlFo1OYogUvExonO5Cioslqmg3UMqBMhVsjncqFm8FhsBCkXB4ji3Zdk6DOUKr7R1Urf3gTVF5CuvWNg2vI2t00jzsQcNCm1Vfj2x3E7V1t0eyw5ih+xUz3txba7fiREfD85XG53B6qgAKmRChhUIDJhsFbpsCJ5ZheeZ2AWFbkjslJlpoR5EFWmI1vOJ6Lk2hrGm2srgmUFRVBgGA9nEqEOBKj4UM+spXuOKqLD+mh-gBQFgLORYLg22Errh658oRlTVDutr7g6lzIRhNLup6FAXvRAa9qS3QkcgABCUgAOpQLJ0ATJwUwUDMk7sXgLD3sgghSCMKhjJc75xhpNmjOMqb-MgGbgTCcKIsi0EXFchZ7PBpaEkh5FxAgAEYJk5qaBUZwAOSWdZUC2WMSWBsQ6HcfqzariaaUALSVHZZhkShfYDlZLnlYp4A0Jp6WuUFcR5UuBX8SVZVjKJe4HpJUUxXFnaJUlNVpRlZhZeErp6V6vkNRxJhVpZ7YjtNDmIQ8L4QNN5liB5Xk0hBvlQaigWHVioX4uFvZiNFICxXyCWGMl62ytNs1xLlmE8cuLYmhtWSla5lWVtVEog-trnLTQe3TW1YgdbxQN4WaYPlf1doSdligja9401TD3349JEILfJS1jkpLAdKSXTaGpzUHZMlgmYsU7XrsPypVI23hZ+zwrmZ7kwJ5YGnT5Pp+fmV3Beh92Rb9t0U3SANdWuaUQ1Wk0C7TjWPGq04cddBPPaNb3JfrUA-Sj-35Th2tSDj4mHu1J5UwphsrfTfaWUJxEYM1guxsLQyJu8pvmxEEsnRCZ2yxdaKx8WavK0Gqs4qWqOA4V3IlUHInZXrErFyRoe+4xJs88jxBPS98XE+X5TCZXUj28eNJYfn3VSMVFekdaYmDeT81notsvLaXAcSpAhlhx+8aLKgkxi3Ex1S4nMu5v5l313BOd3bGt5Hwheda0VA-aMImi61DuwL2A8PG2vhnsYfyCN1bLdP5MXcXSO06s7a+UBiq3xZG7Mec0vaT2ptPX2s9GYwF4NYMAwAALfyqAwCAqoziSEMEUDwhgAA00QwDuHsDEC4NcN4WwkA4BIhh2J0JjgAXmQBQFQSgvjggQDgyA7EESzGSkcMAZgqAAHopEAHd5HglkQAZnBOyQwUiABMAAGHRUiMDMKSuQwh2UYDsk8lkXYDB3DxAoVQr+x0rFQGQOwlxyAkpUxIEaLKadv4xV2GYKQSpnG2KgJTeBniVBHgCVUcAp45IKX0Sw025M2gTE0OKOOnlHHONcUlUAIBoC9FQAAWQADLeOCok9i4J8mFJKaU4JjiIS1KgEUspIo0kZMqcw6pA4ACClCDCCF4JAM4jjyFNK8I4nwKT-bp2PkwpJPN2idAsfOTAOAaDoGwMEggABIA5ezGjSBoElbRGilHFQAIxaOuYY-Ahy9mBDcecy5NzioaPuY8vIBRTkvASLYWRXzDmpGQJybZOArmclIQ8w5Q8aAAFYYWPPMJYcgNg7CnPuXOJQqh1CqXsElbFRZQBJBSFEeA6SIAwrnGwSgXAaBXJpUWEgxzmgFNkXQXBlxmWYjIJQHgEBOVyEdLCvZbRmD4DWWlEgsjdJnicZwgR2RID4JSoY66BKaDJRKnKvSTikrIAANSeUkNgfhygjT4uZjMZwrgiWBXBMUfgPKWBJQoAwOAxVIhJRoGarANSKAwraFcTAzkoA6X1cwGVeqFXgimq5YJyrcFqsMBqn4Wq3E9VcvckN0QZis1ctGqQsr5UWCgAJWG5Uk2CLwYsD66aWCZqSjDLGmVg2hpmIjItQA)

Comment: Did you debug it using some more `console.log` statements? before and after `bar_wrapper.barGroup = ...` line execution, for example?

Comment: Please [edit] this to provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to demonstrate the issue for ourselves without unrelated errors to cause distractions.  Right now [if I try that](https://tsplay.dev/mZyg9N) I get a bunch of issues unrelated to your question. Could you clear those up?  As far as I can tell you never created any instances of your classes (`<BarGroup>` is just a type *assertion* and has no runtime effect). If you want instances you need `new BarGroup` somewhere.  That's probably your issue but please clear up any extraneous problems first so we can be sure.

Comment: @jcalz I updated my question to have a hopefully executable sample.

Comment: @hiddenUser you have never created any instances of your class. You create some SVG element and then tell Typescript to pretend that it is an instance of your class. Check out [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements), in particular how to register and how to instantiate them.

Comment: @Thomas that looks like the right answer; do you want to write it up and post it?

Comment: @Thomas I tried to use `window.customElements.define` but it appears that only works for `HtmlElements`. Well I still learned something new so thank you.